# I need to have MS Access to count how many "Always" replies from a combo list from many fields

Tags: ms-access, count, report

I need to have MS Access to count how many "Always" replies from a combo list from many fields.

Example: I need to know how many "Always" replies for `[SafetyGlasses], [HardHats], [RespiratoryEquipment], [HearingProtection], [GlovesWorn]` + many more.

I tried

```
=Sum(IIf([SafetyGlasses]="Always"AND[HardHats]="Always"))
```

It didn't work.

Then in another field I need it to multiply that number by 3 (I think this one will be easy to do).

Comment: You need DCount. e.g. DCount ("Always","Your table/query", "Your field = 'ALWAYS'")

Comment: I cleaned up your formatting, but you should explain in more detail what happened when it "didn't work."

Comment: In your sample you count how often "Always" was used in SafetyGlasses AND at the same time used in HardHats. I think what you want is OR not AND.

Comment: I'm very confused. "From a combo list from many fields".. Where do we need to actually calculate the replies? Your IIF is completely wrong, also.